# C# MVC Project throws HTTP Error 404.7 - Not Found The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

The MVC project has a Startup.cs file in its root. When i run the project it throws

> HTTP Error 404.7 - `Not Found. The request filtering module is configured to deny the file extension

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <add value="Startup.cs" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I added the following lines of config inside `system.webserver` tag - but there is no change:

```
<security>
    <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="true">
            <remove fileExtension="." />
            <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
    </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to add any [defaultDocuments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/defaultdocument/), and should not use `cs` files there.

If you are using the [default route](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/#default-route), it is sufficient to add a `Home` controller with a `Index` action, which will be called by default. You can adapt the default route to use another controller/action.